# Get Specific information from thrown exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, stack-trace, system.diagnostics

Lets consider that we have an Exception ex thrown in the code. Now in the catch body, I want to have access to six pieces of information:

1. Solution Name
2. Project Name
3. NameSpace Name
4. File Name
5. Method Name
6. Line Number

What I already know is that using

```
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(e, true);
```

I can have access to some of these information(full path of file, line number, etc). But still this information is not all I need. For example, I do not know how to extract solution name or namespace name from trace. Apparently parsing the path for the file is also not an option because different errors can have several layers of file and folders hierarchy and one global rule does not work for all of the errors.

I wonder is there any way to have access programmatically to these info?

Many thanks.

Comment: Things like "solution" and "project" are compile-time only concepts (specific to Visual Studio, even -- a compiler is not required to partition code this way). They are not reflected in the binaries or debug symbols, and hence not available to the runtime. You could embed these explicitly in the assembly with attributes and/or generated code, but you'd still have to handle the case where they're not available. Namespace, while not immediately available in the stack frame, can be determined from the name of the type the method is in (`.GetMethod().ReflectedType.Namespace`).

Comment: ex.ToString() is the maximum amount of information you will get from this. As @JeroenMostert said, Solutions and Projects are a Compiler only thing. Or even a Visual Studio only thing. However that should also be kinda obvious, as the Namespace/Function names are in the stack trace and you should know wich programm is throwing the Exception before you can debug it.

Comment: There are two articles on Exception handling that I link often, and t hose might help you figure out what to do: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: Do you want to have the information you've listed about the point where the exception was originally thrown, or about the point where the exception is caught?

Comment: I want to get the information from the point where the exception was originally thrown.

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood you're not going to get something totally ideal for what you're asking for, but I'll share some tools and thoughts you might not have known about or considered:

1. There are some attributes ([`CallerFilePathAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute?view=netframework-4.8), [`CallerLineNumberAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerlinenumberattribute?view=netframework-4.8), and [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=netframework-4.8) which, when added to an optional method parameter, will cause the compiler to automatically insert a default value based on the context of the code being compiled. You could create a helper method with attributes like this to capture the information you want.
2. There are tools like Fody, known as "IL Weavers", which can run after the main compile process and change the compiled code in a particular way. For example, your code could be written to make a simple call to one method, but when it's compiled the weaver could change the code to create a bunch of contextual information and pass it to a logging method.
3. If you're organizing your code well, you can often ensure that the namespace, class, and method (which are all captured as part of the stack trace) are enough information that you can guess the solution, project, and File Name.
4. When you're catching an exception, you typically want to either log what happened and handle the exception in a particular way, or simply wrap the exception in another exception with more contextual information. If you choose the latter, then the namespace, class, and method name will get included in the stack trace of the thrown exception. So when it's logged further up the stack you'll have access to that data.